# i can not compare two expressions in Bash

Tags: bash, operator-keyword

I'm trying to write an expression like this one ---> if `[ $condition1 ] && [ $condition2 ]` in bash but i keep getting the same error all the times

```
syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./leer.sh: line 25: `elif [[ "$($(date +%Y) -eq $ano)"  && "$($(date +%m) -lt $mes)" ]]'
```

That part of the code is:

```
elif [[ $($(date +%Y) -eq $year)  && $($(date +%m) -lt $month) ]]
then
echo "Well done";
```

Comment: Please post your entire if block

Comment: Well, it's the same erroneous syntax, but the posted code segment and the error message do not match! (`$ano`/`$year`, `$mes`/`$month`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of thing wrong here:

- your condition does not start with `if` but with `elif`
- you are missing the final `fi`
- You try to execute the logical expression using a second `$(...)`

Do you try to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

year=2013
month=11

if [[ $(date +%Y) -eq $year && $(date +%m) -lt $month ]]; then
  echo "Well done"
fi
```